# pyodbc.ProgrammingError: Attempt to use a closed cursor

Tags: python-3.x

I have this method on my class:

```
def exec_query(self, dbms, connection_string, sql):
    self.dbms = dbms
    self.connection_string = connection_string
    self.sql = sql
    self._connection, self._cursor = self._mydb(self.dbms, self.connection_string)
    self._result = None
    self.query_result = []
    try:
        self._cursor.execute(self.sql)
        self.collected_data = self._cursor
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    self._cursor.close()
    self._connection.close()
    return self.collected_data
```

Then I tried to get it's return value outside the class. And I got this error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: Attempt to use a closed cursor.
```

Can't I assign the cursor to a variable? And why?

What I want to do is to process the cursor outside the class. Basically, I can just do .fetchall() and get the data then close the cursor. But .fetchall() eats the memory. So, I want to process the cursor outside.

Comment: If you want to use the cursor outside the function then don't close it within the function.

Comment: there's no other way? i just don't want to leave the cursor and connection open.

Comment: If you want an answer more specific to your situation you'll have to provide more detail (by editing your question). E.g., what do you want to do with the cursor outside the function?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: All I can say is that if you want to use the cursor outside the class, then obviously you can't close it inside the class. Close it after you finish using it.

Comment: I guess, I just need to create another method that will close the cursor and connection. Thanks BTW. I just really thought that I can assign the cursor to a variable and use it outside.

Comment: I don't like chat. I'm sure you can figure it out yourself at this point. Python 3 sqlite documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1):

`self.collected_data` is just another name for the exact same object as `self._cursor`.  If you close `self._cursor` then `self.collected_data` is also closed.

You need to either use

```
self.collected_data = self.cursor.fetch_all()
```

(or whatever) to save the actual data, or leave the connection and cursor open, process your data outside the class, and then call a `close` method.

You may want to look at making your class usable as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__enter__#context-manager-types), then use it something like this:

```
with db_connection.exec_query(dbms, connection_string, sql) as data:
    # process data
    while data:
        row in data.fetch_one()
        do_something_with_row()
# on exit, cursor is closed
```

I probably have the particulars on the `while data` wrong, but hopefully you get the idea.  Your exec_query would look something like this:

```
class exec_query:
    def __init__(self, dbms, connection_string, sql):
        self.dbms = dbms
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        self.sql = sql
        self._connection, self._cursor = self._mydb(self.dbms, self.connection_string)
        self._result = None
        self.query_result = []
        self._cursor.execute(self.sql)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self._cursor
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self._cursor.close()
        self._connection.close()
```